# Modulo calculation in mod 35

Tags: number-theory

I have a problem with number theory. I want to calculate 7^242 in mod 35, and have tried Euler totient function, but not come a long way with that.

Also tried
7^241 * 7^1 = 7 * 7 = 49 in mod 241.
And if the residue is 49 in mod 241, then 7^242 mod 35 would be 14.

Any tips?

Preben

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?  or have you calculated the first few powers of $7\bmod 35$?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a consequence of Carmichael's generalization of the Euler–Fermat theorem:

> If $n$ is square-free, then $a^{\lambda (n)+1} \equiv a \bmod n$ for all integers $a$. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length)]

Since $35=5 \cdot 7$ is square-free and $\lambda(35)=lcm(\phi(5),\phi(7)=12$, we get
$$
7^{12k+1} \equiv 7 \bmod 35
\implies
7^{242} = 7^{241} 7 \equiv 7^{2} \bmod 35
$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$7 $ and $ 35 $ are not relatively prime. You cannot use Euler's Theorem based on the Totient Function. 
But you can try computing successive powers of $7$.

$$7^2=49 \equiv  14 \mod 35$$

$$7^3\equiv 98 \equiv 28 \equiv -7$$

$$7^4 \equiv -14$$
$$7^5 \equiv 7$$

$$7^6 \equiv 14 ...$$

Answer (score 0):

$7^{242}\equiv0\bmod7$ and $7^{242}\equiv2^{242}\equiv2^2=4\bmod 5$.

Now can you figure out $7^{242} \bmod35$?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit off.
So if you have 0 mod 7 and 4 mod 5 is has to be 14 mod 35?

Comment: You got it, @Preben; I used the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Sorry, last stupid question. How did you go from 2^242 = 2^2 ?

Comment: $2^4\equiv1\pmod5$ by Fermat's little theorem, so $2^{240}=(2^4)^{60}\equiv1\pmod5$

Comment: Thanks for much needed assistance

Answer (score 0):

Write 242 in base 2, $i.e.$ $$242=a_02^0+a_12^1+a_22^2+a_32^3+...$$ where $a_i=$ 0 or 1. Then simultaneosly calculate, modulo 35, $$(\text{i}) \qquad7^{2^0},7^{2^1},7^{2^2},7^{2^3},...$$ $[N.B.$ The first number is 7, each subsequent number is the square of the preceding, modulo 35] and $$(\text{ii})answer=1 \times x_0 \times x_1\times x_2\times x_3 \times ...$$ modulo 35 where $$x_i=1 \text { if } a_i=0,x_i=7^{2^i} \text { if } a_i=1$$